# Please help fix my code: print a list of intersections separated by space

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, nested-loops

I have a code that prints a list of the intersections from two sequences (even duplicates) (so I can't use set() function).

here is my code:

```
print("This program finds the intersection of two sets")

sequenceOne = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: ")
sequenceTwo = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: ")

sequenceOne = sequenceOne.split()
sequenceTwo = sequenceTwo.split()
listOfIntersection = []


for i in sequenceOne:
    for j in sequenceTwo:
        if i == j:
            sequenceTwo.remove(i)
            listOfIntersection.append(j)



print('{',(", ".join(str(i) for i in listOfIntersection)), '}')
```

for this code, I need to use nested loops, and the output needs to be between curly braces {}.
the problem is in my output, its wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

My output:

```
Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: 12 k e 34 1.5 12 hi 12 0.2
Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: 1.5 hi 12 0.1 54 12 hi hi hi

The intersection of these two sets is { 12, 12, 1.5, hi, hi, hi }
```

desired output:

```
The intersection of these two sets is {12, 12, 1.5, hi}
```

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Is the problem with _formatting_ (extra spaces before the first item and after the last item), or _content_ (`hi` appearing three times instead of once)?

Comment: I am not sure why you would expect 12 to be printed twice but 'hi' to only be printed once. You should run this in DeBug mode, you will see exactly what it's doing and why the results are what you are getting

Comment: @JohnGordon, the spaces are also a problems, but the main one is (hi) appearing more than once. since it only intersects once between the two sequences

Comment: @JD2775 its basically finding the intersections or matches between the two sequences. if it occurs in both sequences, it adds it to the printout, so 12 appear twice in both sequences, where hi appear once in the first sequence

Comment: DarrylG Yes, I have tried this method and it works, but its not nested loops. I need to implement nested loops

Comment: @MSS98--did you check out all the methods in the link?  The method by DrFalcon for instance (last method) uses nested loops.

Comment: Use a set instead of a list for keeping the intersections.

Comment: @JohnGordon using set, will remove duplicates. where in this program, if a duplicate occurs it should also store it.

Comment: I'm really confused -- earlier you said that printing `hi` more than once is a problem, but now you say that each duplicate should be kept?

Comment: @JohnGordon basically if the duplicate occurs in both sets. for example: ' ' 'seq one: 12 hi 12 hi hi ' ' ' seq Two: 12 12 hi 2  ' ' ' the output should be {12, 12, hi} so if the number or string occurs in both sequences. like connect the same element to each other once

Comment: @JohnGordon so its every time you find a couple (1 from seq one and 1 from seq two)